# Resize the output size of pywebio input

Tags: python

[image]Hello,

The output of pywebio’s input command occupies too much space on the output screen. Is there a way to reduce its size?

```
from pywebio.input import *
var1 = input(“var1”, type=TEXT, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pywebio.config()` to add a css rule:

```py
@config(css_style="#input-container{margin: 0 100px;}")
def main():
    input()

start_server(main, port=8080)
```

Related doc:
https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platform.html#pywebio.config

Comment: Thanks Wei. I have tried these changes and size on the screen has not changed. Please let me know what I am missing. I am using chrome on mac, btw.