# config decorator in pywebio does not seem to be working

Tags: python, css, google-chrome, safari

I am playing with pywebio settings to change the display size of pywebio input. Following the directions from [Resize the output size of pywebio input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773732/resize-the-output-size-of-pywebio-input/70785665#70785665), I tried the following which did not change the display size at all. I get the same result on both chrome and safari.

```
from pywebio import config, session
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *

# session.set_env(output_max_width='100px')
@config(css_style="#input-container{margin: 0 10px;}")
# @config(css_style="* { color:red }")
def run1():
    # put_text("Hello Python")
    input()
run1()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pywebio.config()` cann't be used as decorator in script mode, so you need call this function directly. And in your code, the css rule `#input-container{margin: 0 10px;}` means set the horizontal margin of input box to 10px, however, 10px is too small to see any differences.

Here is a working example:

```py
from pywebio import config
from pywebio.input import *

config(css_style="#input-container{margin: 0 auto; width: 200px}")
input()
```

You can just change the `200px` as you want.